# PHPExcel: How to get style from a row or range of cells and apply to another

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to get the style of a row e.g. ("A3:V3"), pass it to an array, and then use that array with the `applyFromArray();` function.

Here is what i tried:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$style = $sheet->getStyle("A3:V3");
$sheet->getStyle("A$totalRows:V$totalRows")->applyFromArray($style);
```

This throws the error **'Invalid style array passed.'**

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this in the docs - "If you want to copy the ruleset to other cells, you can duplicate the style object"

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2'), 'B3:B7');`

So i didn't have to do this anymore. Should have just searched a little more.